# I am Login my Backend page he is getting error Username and password does not match, But my email id and password are correct in MySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer-php

I am Login my Backend page he is getting error Username and password does not match, But my email id and password are correct in MySQL Server.

What is the problem in my code? Why I don't log in my page. Thank you

**AuthController.php**

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use App\Models\Block;

 use App\User;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 use Session;

class AuthController extends Controller

{

    public function getLogin(){
        return view('login');
    }
    public function login(Request $request){
        // dd($request->all());

        if(  Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
                // login code here
                return redirect('/');
        }
        Session::flash('danger', 'Username and password does not match');
        return redirect('login');

        // login failed here


    }

}
'''
```

**LoginBlade.php**

```
'''
</head>
<body>

    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-65 p-b-50">
            <form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST"  action="{{URL::to('login')}}">
                @csrf
                @include('backend.layouts.alerts')
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-33">
                        Account Login
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input  @error('email') is-invalid @enderror " data-validate = "Valid email is required: valid@email.xyz">
                        <input class="input100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                        <span class="focus-input100-1"></span>
                        <span class="focus-input100-2"></span>
                    </div>
                    @error('email')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror

                    <div class="wrap-input100 rs1 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required" >
                        <input class="input100 @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"  required>
                        <span class="focus-input100-1"></span>
                        <span class="focus-input100-2"></span>
                    </div>
                    @error('password')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-20">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn" value="submit">
                            Sign in
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: when registering a new user make sure the password should `bcrypt()`. Otherwise login not work

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote isn't too far off, The most likely culprit for the issue you are having is how you register or create your user.
This would work provided somewhere in your Registration controller you are hashing the password using bcrypt() or Hash::make()

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return view('login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // validate your request
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) return redirect('/');

        return redirect('login')
            ->with('danger', 'Username and password does not match');
    }

    protected function register(Request $request)
    {
        // validate your request
        $data = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```